# Access Report with null column

Tags: ms-access, report

I´m not sure if my title is the best, I'll explain my problem:

I have a table `t_teamschedule`, that keeps the data about who is playing and when. There are another table `t_tvts` that keeps what tv channel is going to transmit the game. I'm making a report to show this information.

I have a problem with those games that are not going to be in any tvchannel, I want that games in the report, with the tv column empty, but they just doesn't appear. I was looking if there are any way to put some default value so if the select give me no value it add anyway the game, but I don't find anything like that.

Comment: Please show us the SQL text of your query. (If you want us to correct a problem in your query, we need to see it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your *inner join* in your query between the two tables with a *left outer join*.

In the query designer, that means a small arrow at the junction between the t_tvts table and the line that shows the join.

Comment: thank you very much. Thats work perfectly.